# How to attach a headboard to my bedspring?

Tags: woodworking, bedroom

I bought a headboard that looks like this :
[image: Headboard]

I want to attach it to a bedspring that looks like this:
[image: Bedspring]

The headboard and box spring are both single bed size from different bed sets. The headboard isn't that heavy (knowing that I'm not known for being very strong, I was able to carry it alone). It is made of pine wood and padded with a soft material (foam?). I'd rather not have to drill into my walls to install it.

The headboard didn't come with any literature. Perhaps there was for the box spring, but I may have lost it.

How to do it? What exactly are the tools I need and what instructions to follow? I searched on the internet to no avail. (The two steel elements on the headboard are slides, from what I've found on the internet.)

Comment: Welcome. Unfortunately your question is quite broad, essentially asking for a guidebook on basic carpentry. Also, we know nothing about the internal structure of those components. It's difficult to provide useful answers beyond general suggestions. Please take the [tour] to learn how we're different from a discussion forum.

Comment: I've made some updates. Please revise further to clarify or correct. And do take the [tour].

Comment: Are the 2 slides on the headboard wider at the top than the bottom by a small margin? If so, there should be two more that go with those that are separate, or could be separated to attach to the base. Then one will slide into the other for support.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this.

That bed base is too flimsy, designed to be just enough to support the person lying on it.  The headboard, if pushed or pulled from its top, will act as a huge lever if attached to the side of the base, and it will tear that side apart because it's not built for that.

Your best options are:

- Just sandwich the headboard between the bed and the wall, free standing.
- Screw the headboard to wall studs
- Remove the bed base from its legs and place it instead inside a conventional steel or wood bed frame.  Attach the headboard to the frame using brackets designed for that frame.  Probably just nuts and bolts.
- Build legs for the headboard out of 2x4s and attach it to them, so it won't be supported by the bed or the wall.

Comment: I would go with the wall mount option. Unless both the bed and the headboard have a steel construction of some sort and you can create a sturdy connection that can take the torque of someone leaning up against it, it's better to just mount it straight to the wall and move the bed in place.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a "make it up as you go" proposition. In other words, browse a hardware store's selection of bolts and brackets, mentally exploring how each thing you see might be applied to the problem.

Simple: a set of bolts and nuts to fasten the head board to the end-face of the bedspring. Some kind of backing or stiffening may prove to be required: that's a relatively heavy-looking headboard and it is tall in comparison to the width of the bedspring face to which it could mount. The height translates to leverage which the end face may not be prepared to accept.

Medium: Attach the head board to the side rails of the bedspring. This might be done with an L-shaped metal bracket and bolts/screws. The long leg of the L would be fastened to the side rail of the bed; the short leg of the L would be fastened to the headboard. This will handle the leverage problem much better than the simple method above would.

Frame challenge: What about mounting the headboard to the wall and placing the bedspring standing freely in front of it? I've seen this done in several hotels.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The headboard and box spring both correspond to a single bed. The headboard isn't that heavy (knowing that I'm not known for being very strong, I was able to carry it alone). It is made of pine wood and padded with a soft material (foam?). I'd rather not have to drill into my walls to install it...

Comment: I think I will go for the medium solution. But I  can't seem to figure out where is the "sliding" part implied by the two elements attached to the headboard...

Comment: @pilou If I understood correctly the headboard was purchased separately from the bed -- the two were not designed to go together. The hardware on the headboard was designed for assembly to a _specific_ bed, but _your_ bed is not that one. The hardware is not universal among beds and yours lacks the specific hardware to match that seen on the headboard. Remove the existing proprietary hardware from the headboard and invent your own custom substitute.